I have a long string of group SMS/MMS messages on my Google Pixel 3 How can I back them up to a computer?
My wife and I run a small real estate business. In the course of our business we often setup a group text between ourselves and the tenants so that everyone is on the same page regarding anything related to the rental unit. Long story short, I need to capture the entire group text chain stored on my pixel 3 and get it a computer so we can submit the entire chain to our attorney. Of course I could screenshot 6 months of texts 1 at a time, but there just HAS to be a better more efficient way. I have access to computers running Windows and Linux as well as an IPad. It would be ideal if I could get this info into my gmail account. Any ideas?
Unfortunately testing indicates the suggested duplicate doesn't appear to apply to MMS..

Does this answer your question? How can I copy entire chain of text messages (not just a single one) with the stock Android messages app?

@beeshyams Sadly the referenced answer doesn't appear to apply to MMS, thanks for the attempt! I did try SMS Backup and restore targeting email as the target, but I didn't get the desired results. I couldn't even locate the group text messages in the result.

Thanks, I don't use MMS so you must be right//Did you try to restore as pdf by using the print option as indicated in the linked answer? // I tested again and pdf gets generated // But I can't say a thing about MMS except save the images elsewhere and use a PDF writer to insert them in the pdf generated//If that works, you can mail pdf to your attorney

This app claims to do what you want, I haven't tried it// It's a paid app beyond a limit

@beeshyams Thanks for the suggestion, however I went another direction for free,as Im not a fan of untested solutions. My solution is below.

Good that you found a way +1

I solved this by archiving the conversation on my google pixel 3 phone and then logging into my google account and navigating to messages.google.com
1: https://messages.google.com/web which gave me the entire several months of conversation  in my default browser on my Linux Mint PC. I selected the conversation from the left hand column which populated the right hand column with the data required. redacted Example below.
